# Matplotlib NavigationToolbar2QT shows only disabled left and right arrows. How to display Zoom and Pan buttons?

Tags: python, matplotlib, qt5, pyside2

I'm using (but am new to) matplotlib and PySide2 to draw a chart embedded inside a QWidget. I want the chart to have a NavigationToolbar2QT with Zoom and Pan buttons. But I get only disabled left and right arrow buttons in the NavigationToolBar. Here are the relevant portions of my code:

```
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QWidget, QVBoxLayout
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar


class ChartWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, algo_index, *args, **kwargs):
        QWidget.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.setLayout(QVBoxLayout())
        self.canvas = AlgoCanvas.get_plot_canvas(algo_index, self)
        self.toolbar = NavigationToolbar(self.canvas, self)
        self.layout().addWidget(self.toolbar)
        self.layout().addWidget(self.canvas)
```

And here is the result I'm getting:

[image]

What do I have to do to get Zoom and Pan buttons on the NavigationToolbar2QT? Any help would be appreciated?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @eyllanesc I think my example is minimal and reproducible (as per the link you provided). Could you please elaborate what do you find lacking in it?

Comment: Your code is minimal but not reproducible. The logic of MRE is that other users can reproduce your problem with a copy-paste, and obviously there is a lot of code that isn't defined as "something_index", "AlgoCanvas"

Comment: I suppose the buttons are there, just not visible because black buttons on black background make everything black.

Comment: For example, using the code from [the official matplotlib example for Qt](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/user_interfaces/embedding_in_qt_sgskip.html) + your piece of incomplete code, I obtained the following: https://i.imgur.com/BxRRurT.png

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Yep! That was the problem. The buttons were hidden by the black background. Thanks v.much for the pointer

Comment: @eyllanesc Thanks v.much for elaborating on MRE. As you can see from my above comment, my problem got solved, but I'll keep your tips in mind when posting questions in the future.

Comment: @nparabz Post the answer of ImportanceOfBeingErnest as an answer

Answer (score 0):

Solved! The buttons were there, but not visible because of the black background.

Thanks v.much @ImportanceOfBeingEarnest for providing the pointer.